# Altium: board cutouts and multiple flex-regions

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am currently trying to create a rigid-flex PCB in Altium according to the following picture:
[image: PCB with cutout and multiple rigid flex sections]
**Purple**: this should be the mechanical bard shape ;
**Red**: flex regions

basically i want to have a foldable PCB with two sections that are connected by multiple flex regions.

**What I know/am familiar with:**

- Layer Stack Manager: I have created a rigid and a flex layer stack
- Board Planning Mode: Assigning Layer stacks to board regions and define bending line/angle/radius for flex parts
- create board cutouts using tools - convert - board cutout

**What i dont know:**

- The board cutout seems to be ignored in board planning mode, so i cannot create flex regions in the red areas whle keeping the inner sections of the purple cutout rigid.

Comment: Did you define your split lines as well as your bend lines? The split lines separate the rigid sections from the flex sections (they allow you to select which stack to use in each section)

Comment: yes I did that.
The cutout is displayed as a dashed line in board planning mode, but the split lines do not snap to it.

Comment: Go through the following videos and you will get idea's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Kyauz058IU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeRd1b6oGto&t=515s

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell from the picture what you're trying to do, but I find when I'm doing rigid flex I try to draw one continuous outline in board planning mode first, including the flex sections. I do the cutouts later.

Your layout and board outline should treat the rigid and flex sections as all one board. After you have an outline defined, you should place cutouts in layout mode, then later go back to board planning mode to set your board section lines.

Keep in mind that the bend lines do nothing for fabrication files, they seem to purely be for visual effects in 3D mode.

Comment: I havent yet, as some other projects got in the way. But I will return to this in some time and let you know